# Enabling CORS on a Racket servlet

Tags: http, server, cors, racket

I'm have a Racket web server using `web-server`, is there a way to enable Cross origin resource sharing (CORS)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes!

A CORS policy is established using HTTP headers on the response. In the Racket web server, as you know, HTTP response values are instances of the [response](https://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server/http.html#(def._((lib._web-server%2Fhttp%2Fresponse-structs..rkt)._response))) struct, which you usually construct through a higher-level function like `response/xexpr` or `response/output`. Precisely what headers you'll want to set depends on your application, but here is a simple example:

```
(response/output
 #:mime-type #"text/javascript"
 #:headers (list (header #"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" #"*"))
 (λ (out)
   (write-bytes #"console.log('Hi, world!')\n" out)))
```

In a real web application, you probably want to generate more than one response with the same headers. I usually make some wrapper functions around `response/output`, `response/xexpr`, etc. to add logic specific to my application. If you are serving a bunch of static files that need CORS headers, you might want to build on the [web-server/dispatchers/dispatch-files](https://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server-internal/dispatch-files.html) module.